# How to getParams type of array

Tags: php, magento, url, parameters, param

In Magento, as usually we used to get param

```
http://magento.com/customer/account/view/id/122
```

we can get the param by

```
$x = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
echo $x; // value is 122
```

now as far as i know the $x just to get a string from the param.

is there any way to get $x as an array?

as example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 122
    [1] => 233
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid it is currently not possible for Zend Framework or Magento to pass array param to zend url.

Here is a bug reported on [passing get variable as an array](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2986).

Answer (score 5):

For example:

```
http://magento.com/customer/account/view/id/122-233

$x = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$arrayQuery = array_map('intval', explode('-', $x)));
var_dump($arrayQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean get all of the parameters as an array (might be a varien object):

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use brackets on your query params, like http://magento.com/customer/account/view/?id[]=123&id[]=456

then after running the following, $x will be an array.

```
$x = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion if you want inputs from visitor as array then instead of passing them in URL as GET params pass those as POST variable.

Then $_POST  will have all and you can $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

Answer (score 1):

With Zend Framework 1.12 this is possible with just the method getParam(). Notice the result of getParam() is **NULL for no available key**, a **string for 1 key**, and an **array for multiple keys**:

**No 'id' value**

```
http://domain.com/module/controller/action/

$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
// NULL
```

**Single 'id' value**

```
http://domain.com/module/controller/action/id/122

$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
// string(3) "122"
```

**Multiple 'id' values:**

```
http://domain.com/module/controller/action/id/122/id/2584

$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
// array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "122" [1]=> string(4) "2584" }
```

This could be problematic if you always expect a string in your code, and for some reason more values are set in the url: In some cases you can for example run into the error "***Array to string conversion***". Here are some tricks to avoid such errors, to make sure you always get the type of result you need from getParam():

If you want the $id to be an **array** (or NULL if param is not set)

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if($id !== null && !is_array($id)) {
    $id = array($id);
}

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/
// NULL

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/id/122
// array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "122" }
```

If you **always** want the $id to be an **array** (no NULL value if not set, just empty array):

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if(!is_array($id)) {
    if($id === null) {
        $id = array();
    } else {
        $id = array($id);
    }
}

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/
// array(0) { }

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/id/122
// array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "122" }
```

Same as above in one line (no NULL, always array):

```
$id = (array)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

If you want the $id to be a **string** (the **first available** value, keeps NULL intact)

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if(is_array($id)) {
    $id = array_shift(array_values($id));
}

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/
// NULL

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/122/id/2584
// string(3) "122"
```

If you want the $id to be a **string** (the **last available** value, keeps NULL intact)

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if(is_array($id)) {
    $id = array_pop(array_values($id));
}

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/
// NULL

http://domain.com/module/controller/action/122/id/2584/id/52863
// string(5) "52863"
```

Maybe there are shorter/better ways to fix these 'response-types' of getParam, but if you are going to use the above scripts, it could be cleaner to create another method for it (extended helper or something).